# Spark join two dataframes on best .startswith match

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Two dataframes with phone numbers with ids that could only be matched via regex, e.g.

| idPrefix | other columns |
| --- | --- |
| 420 |  |
| 42055 |  |
| 420551 |  |

| phoneNumber | other columns |
| --- | --- |
| 420551666 |  |
| 421709560 |  |

I would need to join these dataframes on the best match of `idPrefix` to the `phoneNumber`, matching the longest starting prefix possible, if there is one. E.g. if there were any option to join on longest `idPrefix` for `phoneNumber.startswith(idPrefix)`, that would be great.

e.g. result would look like
[image]

I tried a few UDFs with regex instead of a `df.join()`, but there does not seem to be a way to have a dataframe as an input to UDF.

Answer (score 2):

Join on `startsWith` condition then use `row_number` to keep longest `idPrefix` per `phoneNumber`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df1 = Seq(("420"), ("42055"), ("420551")).toDF("idPrefix")
val df2 = Seq(("420551666"), ("421709560")).toDF("phoneNumber")

val df = (df2
  .join(df1, col("phoneNumber").startsWith(col("idPrefix")), "left")
  .withColumn(
    "rn",
    row_number().over(
      Window.partitionBy("phoneNumber").orderBy(length(col("idPrefix")).desc)
    )
  )
  .filter("rn = 1")
  .drop("rn")
)

df.show
//+-----------+--------+
//|phoneNumber|idPrefix|
//+-----------+--------+
//|  421709560|    null|
//|  420551666|  420551|
//+-----------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

It's true that you can use directly the startsWith in the join, but this will require that one of the tables can be broadcasted, if this case can't be achieved it will become a join with a cartesian product complexity making it very inefficient. If both dataframes are very large, you can try to make a join first by prefixes and then filter by the startsWith.

The code will look something like this:

```
val df1 = Seq(("420"), ("42055"), ("420551")).toDF("idPrefix")
val df2 = Seq(("420551666"), ("421709560")).toDF("phoneNumber")

val prefixSize = df1.select(min(length(col("idPrefix")))).as[Int].head()
//takes the length of the smallest prefix, or if its static set it hardcoded

val df = df2
  .join(df1, substring(col("idPrefix"), 0, prefixSize) === substring(col("phoneNumber"), 0, prefixSize), "left")
  .filter(col("phoneNumber").startsWith(col("idPrefix")) || col("idPrefix").isNull) //join by the prefix and filter all false elements
  .groupBy("phoneNumber").agg(max(struct(length(col("idPrefix").as("size")), col("idPrefix"))).as("idPrefix"))
  .withColumn("idPrefix", col("idPrefix.idPrefix")) //take the maximum length for the phone number in a single aggregation

df.show
//+-----------+--------+
//|phoneNumber|idPrefix|
//+-----------+--------+
//|  420551666|  420551|
//|  421709560|    null|
//+-----------+--------+
```

Comment: As I said this is a solution if none of the tables can be broadcasted. The result is the same, but in your case, startsWith is not an equijoin condition, the one that allows using hash merge join or sort-merge join.
StartsWith has to try all possible left cases against all possible right cases to see if its true or false, that's why it's a cartesian product. In case that broadcast is not possible, to reduce the number of comparations that has to be done, it's better to bucket the data. https://towardsdatascience.com/demystifying-joins-in-apache-spark-38589701a88e

Comment: Thanks @Alfilercio! I missed this part